# Rally: UserStory Count for a given project

Tags: java, rally

I am doing java code for fetching all userstories for a given project.

```
    QueryRequest hrRequest = new QueryRequest("hierarchicalrequirement");
    hrRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","Children","Release"));
    hrRequest.setWorkspace(wsRef);
    hrRequest.setProject(prjRef);
```

the above code will give me all the userstories which are tied to Iterations (i.e., if iteration is blank - this will not fetch that userstory)

but, i need all userstories to be fetched those are available under that project/subproject

Pls help

Thanks 
VG

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic; it probably belongs on a Rally support forum.


Answer (score 0):

You may set a project scope of your request:

```
storyRequest.setProject(projectRef);
```

as long as prior to that projectRef is specified:

```
String projectRef = "/project/2222";
```

Here is a code that prints out story count in a project:

```
public class aRESTstories {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "apiuser@company.com";
            String password = "secret";
            String projectRef = "/project/2222";
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/11111"; 
            String applicationName = "RESTExampleStoriesInProject";


        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   


        QueryRequest storyRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
        storyRequest.setLimit(1000);
        storyRequest.setScopedDown(true);
        storyRequest.setScopedUp(false);
        storyRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        storyRequest.setProject(projectRef);


        QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);
        System.out.println(storyQueryResponse.getResults().size());
    }
}
```